AstroNVim disable neo-tree sitter and replace it with nvim-tree or other
I've been trying out astroNVim works great but due to enterprise limitations i couldnt get neo-treesitter work for some reason and every time i save a file tree sitter crashes throwing a bunch of alert prompts.
I would like to disable neo-tree and replace with nvim-tree or alternative. I tried updating couldn't find a resonable solution could be due to lack of admin privileges on certain folders.
Please help me mitigate this issue.
